# using Copilot in Visual Studio 2022 to document code

Tags: visual-studio, github-copilot

When I write above method "AllNewOpportunities"://document AllNewOpportunities
I get:

```
       //https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/data-platform/webapi/query-expression-web-api
        //https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/data-platform/webapi/query-data-web-api
        //https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/data-platform/webapi/retrieve-multiple-records-web-api
        //https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/data-platform/webapi/retrieve-entity-metadata-web-api
        //https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/data-platform/webapi/retrieve-record-web-api
```

Is there a magic word to make it document code?

Comment: Type "Oh dear text-predictor, I don't want to type a line or two to explain what my code does, so please try to interpret my spaghetti and extract a human-readable summary for me" and see what happens. All hail our AI overlords.

Comment: Love your passion for AI @CodeCaster :-)

Comment: @OferGal did you get this sorted? I have a lot of code I've inherited and it would be nice if AI could do the thing!

Comment: Its a whole new copilot now and it does document(explain)